# Extracting data with a certain pattern from a .txt file

Tags: php, file, text, extract

I have a large `.txt` file that contains a lot of text like this:

```
data-domain="googledotcom"
```

So, I want to extract whatever is in the quotes (in this case `googledotcom`) into a new file. Results should be each separated with a new line (or at least with a tab).

I've looked online and couldn't find an easy way to do it. I might have tagged this question wrong, just because I'm not sure how to accomplish this, thanks for help.

Comment: This may involve regex, hence there is no easy to way to do it. Search for regex

Comment: is every data-domain in new line in 'large .txt file'? And what you mean by 'large'? And yes, easiest way -> please give us longer sample from that file....

Comment: look into http://www.php.net/preg_match

Comment: PLease provide some details about the exact strucutre of those files, and what should be matched and what shouldn't. Also, please note that StackOverflow is there to help with specific problems you came along while programming, not to get someone else to program or google for you. Try something first, if it doesn't work out come back with the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you can use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg-match-all) regex for that:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$test = <<<STR
xxx
data-domain="test1"
yyy data-domain="test2"
zzz
data-domain="test3"
STR;

$results = preg_match_all('/data\-domain\=\"(.+)\"/', $test, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
?>
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test1
    [1] => test2
    [2] => test3
)
```

Dependent on filesize, you should read it by [`fopen()`](http://php.net/fopen) + [`fread()`](http://php.net/fread) (row-by-row if it is large) or by [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file-get-contents) (entire file at once, if it is relatively small). Then analyze it with regular expression and write results to a new file.

Answer (score 3):

```
$text = file('file.txt') ;
foreach ($text as $value) {
    if (preg_match('/"([^"]+)"/', $value, $match)) {
        $domains[] = $match[1];
    }
}
file_put_contents("domains.txt", implode("\n", $domains));
```